# Spinner is not displaying set value in Android fragment

Tags: android, retrofit, android-spinner

I am writing a code where spinner is populated by data coming from webservice. I am using retrofit

```
RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(InterfaceApi.URL).build();
        InterfaceApi interfaceApi = adapter.create(InterfaceApi.class);

        interfaceApi.getAdminLeaveTypes(new Callback<ArrayList<AdminLeaveTypeBeans>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ArrayList<AdminLeaveTypeBeans> adminLeaveTypeBeanses, Response response) {
                if (adminLeaveTypeBeanses.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No record found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < adminLeaveTypeBeanses.size(); i++) {
                        leaveTypeId.add(i, adminLeaveTypeBeanses.get(i).getTypeId());
                        leaveTypeName.add(i, adminLeaveTypeBeanses.get(i).getTypeName());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error..may be webservice not running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("failure: ", "messgae" +error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterLeaveType = new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, leaveTypeName);
        spinnerLeaveAdminType.setAdapter(adapterLeaveType);
```

I looking to set value after selection to spinner.Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line before `setAdapter(..)` :-

```
spinnerLeaveAdminType.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify the adapter for data change after adding item to list

```
adapterLeaveType.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterLeaveType = new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, leaveTypeName);
    spinnerLeaveAdminType.setAdapter(adapterLeaveType);
```

Change it to:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterLeaveType = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, leaveTypeName);
    adapterLeaveType.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerLeaveAdminType.setAdapter(adapterLeaveType);
```